# use javascript variable with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use my javascript variable with laravel.But I'm getting this error.

error:

> Use of undefined constant tag - assumed 'tag'
>
> Use of undefined constant tag - assumed 'tag'

and this is my code.

```
var tag = location.tagCode;
var rfidString = ('{!!\App\Rfid::where('rfid_id', tag)->first()!!}')
var rfid = JSON.parse(rfidString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do XHR request to server along with `tag` then retrieve RFID from server and then assign it to javascript variable.

The way you are doing not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, use json_encode with Array of data.

```
<script>
    window.variable = {!! json_encode([
        'variable' => 'value',
    ]) !!};
</script>
```